# Comma after english word

Tags: numbering, indexing, punctuation, arabic, pagestyle

I am using the Arabic language in writing my latex file, I have a problem in in the comma which appear in there reverse place for the English words, some times I keep some terms in English for the clarification. For example: when writing ،I it is appear as I، in the compiled (pdf) file. This problem happens in the index when I have a Roman number with comma. I am using custom-comma.ist file with  delim_0 ""  and delim_n "، " inside it.

minimal compiled file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{}{
\fancyhead[RE]{\textbf{\small\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fancytext\scriptsize{{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textbf{\small\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\scriptsize{{\leftmark}}}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,color} 
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{morefloats}   
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{mysize}{\fontsize{10}{9.6}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{font=mysize}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand\setrow[1]{\gdef\rowmac{#1}#1\ignorespaces}
\usepackage{makecell}
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\cftsetindents{section}{1em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{1em}{3em}
\oddsidemargin-0.8cm
\evensidemargin-0.8cm
\textwidth18cm
\textheight24cm
%\parindent0cm

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{AlBattar} %


\makeindex

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
%\titleformat{\chapter}
%{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{blue}}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vskip 1 true cm

{\Huge\bf مقدمة الى العلوم }

\vskip 1.5 true cm

{\Huge\bf ميخائيل \& عبدالله 

\vskip 0.5 true cm

الكيمياء العامة

\vskip 0.5 true cm

جامعة العلوم

\vskip 0.5 true cm

الحرم الجامعي ت د 2.2 

\vskip 0.5 true cm

مدينة 66123

\vskip 0.5 true cm

دولة}

\vskip 1.5 true cm

\copyright\today, ميخائيل \& عبدالله 

\end{center}
\newpage
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{مقدمة}
\pagestyle{headings}
%{\bf Introduction}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2em}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{}
\rhead{\textbf{II}}
\lhead{\fancytext\scriptsize{مقدمة}}
\chapter*{مقدمة\markboth{مقدمة}{}}
تُشكل نظرية الكم الأساس لفهم الاوآصر الكيميائية  و التحليل الطيفي. نظراً لأن التأثير  الناتج من التلاعب بالاوآصر الكيميائية يقع في صميم الكيمياء، فإن الفهم الجيد للتآصر الكيميائي إلزامي. هذا بالإضافة إلى الأهمية الكبيرة للتحليل الطيفي في تشخيص المواد و التآصر الكيميائي في تفسير الإكتشافات الكيميائية، لذا فإن الفهم الجيد لنظرية الكم يعتبر عنصر مهم في الكيمياء.
\index{التحليل الطيفي}
\index{نظرية الكم} تُشكل نظرية الكم أيضاً الأساس في مجال النمذجة الكيميائية، \index{النمذجة الكيميائية} 
و الذي يمكن من خلالها دراسة الخصائص و التراكيب ومسارات التفاعل وما إلى ذلك من خلال حسابات الحاسوب. إن السابق يمثل مجال إنشطة البحث المستمرة.
إن نظرية الكم هي النظرية التي يجب إستخدامها في التعامل مع الانظمة الصغيرة جداً. من خلال وجهة النظر هذه، تبدو نظرية الكم ذات صلة محدودة بحياتنا اليومية، حيث إننا  عادةً ما نتعامل مع انظمة أكبر بكثير. لذلك، قد يكون من المدهش معرفة إن ما يقدر بنحو 20\%\
من جميع السلع المنتجة مبنية على التطورات التكنولوجية التي لم تكن لتتواجد بدون نظرية الكم.
إن النمذجة الكيميائية تُشكل اهتمام مُتزايد لمعظم الكيميائيين التجريبيين. بادئ ذي بدء، خلال الوقت الحاضر نادراً ما يتم قبول الأوراق البحثية من قبل المجلات الكيميائية المرموقة إذا لم يتم دعم الدراسات التجريبية واستكمالها بالحسابات النظرية.
فيما يخص أطاريح الدكتوراه، و التي تتضمن نتائج تجريبية بشكل أساسي، من المهم أيضاً تضمين نتائج الدراسات النظرية فيها.
إن العمل العلمي غير المنشور هو عمل لا معنى له، يجب على المرء اّن يدرك إن النشر جزء أساسي من أطروحة الدكتوراه، مما يعني إن الحسابات النظرية تمثل جزء مهم من أي دراسة كيميائية.
في النهاية، يمكن للحسابات النظرية اّن تحل محل جزء كبير من الدراسات التجريبية. يمكن توضيح ذلك من خلال مثال من تجربتنا الخاصة. في جامعة تيانجين في الصين، هناك مجموعة بحثية  تتعامل مع إنتاج مواد لها تطبيقات في الخلايا الشمسية. الهدف هو التعرف على مواد ذات ناتج عالي (على سبيل المثال الحصول على مواد للخلايا الشمسية تعطي اعلى ما يمكن من التيار الكهربائي المتولد من الإشعاع الشمسي).
لهذا الغرض، حوالي 50 عضوا من مجموعة العمل البحثية شخصوا عدد من مشتقات البورفيرينات porphyrins (تُشكل البورفيرينات اللبنات الأساسية لما يُدعى بخلايا كراتزل ،Gr\"atzel و هي نوع من الخلايا الشمسية). إن مشتقات  البورفيرينات تم تحويرها بكل المهارات الممكنة للكيمياء العضوية.
 إن تحضير مركبا جديدا ولاحقاً دراسة اداء المركب يتطلب باحثا لكل عام تقريبا، و في الغالب إن نسبة كبيرة من هذه المركبات الجديدة لا تفي بالمتطلبات. 
 يمكن إجراء الحساب النظري في غضون أسبوع تقريباً، ويمكن للشخص الذي يقوم بمثل هذا الحساب التعامل مع أكثر من مركب واحد على التوازي (على سبيل المثال، 10 مركبات). 
لذلك، يمكن معالجة حوالي خمسمائة من المركبات نظرياً بواسطة باحث واحد كل عام، و هو رقم أكبر بكثير من المركب الواحد الذي يمكن اّن يدرسه الباحث بالطرق العملية. 
حتى إذا كانت الحسابات تخضع لبعض عدم الدقة، فإن نتائج هذه الحسابات مهمة جداً لتحديد المركبات الواعدة المُثلى في المختبر.
لذلك، نُلاحظ أيضاً إن الحسابات النظرية  توفر معلومات مفيدة جداً للباحثين في المجال العملي.
\index{الطاقة الشمسية} 
\index{بورفيرين} 
\index{خلايا كراتزل} \index{الخلايا الشمسية}

نهدف من خلال هذا الكتاب إلى تقديم أسس نظرية الكم بالإضافة إلى أمثلة على تطبيقها في معالجة الانظمة الذرية و الجزيئية. 
إنها هذا الكتاب مخصص  لطلاب الكيمياء في الدراسة الجامعية الاولية. سيكون من المفيد للقراء اّن يمتلكوا الفهم الاولي لنظرية الكم، بما في ذلك هل لديهم معلومات عن المدارات ،orbitals ومبدأ  اوفباو ،Aufbau و الآصرة الكيميائية، وما إلى ذلك. لكن حتى بدون هذه المعرفة المسبقة، يجب اّن يكون من الممكن، من حيث المبدأ، التكيف مع موضوع هذا الكتاب، ويتطلب ذلك بعض الجهد. في بعض الأحيان يتم مناقشة الأمثلة بإيجاز، و التي ستتم مناقشتها بمزيد من التفصيل لاحقاً في هذا الكتاب، و بالتالي فإن هذه المعرفة المسبقة ستكون مفيدة جداً.\\

\noindent مدينة  مارس 2021

\noindent ميخائيل  \& عبدالله 
\newpage
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{}
\renewcommand\contentsname{محتويات الكتاب}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
\markright{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}
\mainmatter
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{ماهي نظرية الكم؟}
\label{sec01}

\section{الفيزياء التقليدية}
\label{sec01a}
\addtocounter{page}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{الفهرس}

\addtocounter{page}{-1}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a compilable minimal working example which will allow users to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: you should clean up your preamble a bit, you load color three times, and xcolor twice. inputenc is useless with unicode engines, and epsfig is obsolete since 20 years.